# How to change configuration at runtime in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I would like to be able to change the configuration settings at runtime when I would handle a request containing a certain custom header that will be sent from my acceptance/smoke tests. The other incoming requests would need to use the default configuration.

For the tests that are hitting the API, I would like to load the JSON file containing the URLs that are going to return mocked data and replace them in the settings.

I have tried different approaches, with the IOptionsSnapshot or the IOptionsMonitor injected where I need the settings, but it doesn't seem to pick up the new values, was trying to replace the configuration values when executing the middleware, but with no luck.

I have seen different approaches that are doing sort of a merge of the configuration of the app settings file with the one that I want to load and discard, could you please tell me, what's the best approach that will work? Isn't there something more simple than reading the JSON file, updating the values, and saving the new app settings file? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just load different configuration in the tests? That's what [environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-5.0) are for.

Comment: You need to have different appsetttngs file per environment and overlay them.  That is how its done in .net core.

Comment: You use the same instance of app for prod and  integration tests? If yes - stop doing this as far as you can. If not - then you can use concept of environment settings files (3rd point [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#default-configuration)).

Comment: @Crowcoder, the setup is a bit different, I'm aware of what you're saying, the idea is that the tests would hit the actual API, more like acceptance tests than integration tests, I think the term should be acceptance tests instead and be able to swap the config dynamically, to return mocked data for 3rd party URLs we use, for example.

Comment: u can put those json file as separate and  use   config.AddJsonFile(
                        "json_array.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro, yes, that's how the API is set up, but we will hit the API with actual requests, more like acceptance tests, as I mentioned in one of my previous comments.

Comment: @GuruStron, no, the flow is controlled, is just for certain lower environments.

Comment: One option that I am aware of would be to use the Key Vault and put different values there, and read the value based on the incoming request, but this would probably mean that I'd need to add conditions and checks in the actual code where we call the 3rd parties, which is not necessarily what I want. The way is done now is by changing the config manually, do a redeploy, change it back when is not needed anymore, would like not to have to do a redeployment every time.

Comment: You can create [custom configuration provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#custom-configuration-provider) then.

Comment: @Guru Stron: I gave it a try, maybe I missed something. The configuration would have already been built and a custom configuration provider would need to access the current HTTP context to read that custom header for the request from the tests, the config would need to be changed based on the request. Though I inject the IHttpContextAccesor in the configuration source then pass it to the custom configuration provider, when I do the bootstrapping and call ConfigureAppConfiguration I would need access to the current HTTP context, which I don't or maybe I'm not aware of how to pass it there.

Comment: This questions is relevant to me, because Testcontainers does not allow for specifying a port number... it's randomly assigned at runtime.  In order to get my repository the appropriate test connection string (without altering production code) it needs to be altered in the tests startup.  We use IConfiguration and it doesn't seem intended to be altered.

Answer (score 2):

**OPTION A**
If you are running tests with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing` library you can play with different environments, environment variables or appsettings files as some have mentioned in the comments.
All my contract/component/functional (however you want to call them) tests under xUnit inherit from a base class that abstracts away the configuration so that the tests can focus on the given/when/then sections.

```
public abstract class Given_When_Then_Test_Async 
    : IAsyncLifetime
{
    public async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        await this.Given();
        await this.When();
    }

    public async Task DisposeAsync() => await this.Cleanup();

    protected virtual Task Cleanup() => Task.CompletedTask;

    protected abstract Task Given();

    protected abstract Task When();
}

public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection Replace<TService>(
        this IServiceCollection services,
        Func<IServiceProvider, TService> implementationFactory,
        ServiceLifetime lifetime)
        where TService : class
    {
        var descriptorToRemove = services.FirstOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(TService));

        services.Remove(descriptorToRemove);

        var descriptorToAdd = new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(TService), implementationFactory, lifetime);

        services.Add(descriptorToAdd);

        return services;
    }
}

public abstract class FunctionalTest
    : Given_When_Then_Test_Async
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    protected HttpClient HttpClient { get; }
    protected IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    protected FunctionalTest()
    {
        var server =
            new TestServer(
                new WebHostBuilder()
                    .UseStartup<Startup>()
                    .UseCommonConfiguration()
                    .UseEnvironment("Test") // here I specify that my environment is called Test, so it'll look for appsettings.Test.json
                    .ConfigureTestServices(ConfigureTestServices));

        HttpClient = server.CreateClient();
        _serviceProvider = server.Services;
        Configuration = _serviceProvider.GetService<IConfiguration>();
    }

    protected T GetService<T>() where T : class
    {
        return _serviceProvider.GetService<T>();
    }

    protected virtual void ConfigureTestServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // replace here whichever service you want for all tests
    }
}
```

So after all that boilerplate your tests are clean, use the real implementation (the same Startup) with only the mocks you specify, if any.

```
public class Given_Clients_In_Database_When_Getting_Filtered_Clients_By_Name
    : FunctionalTest
{
    private string _url;
    private HttpResponseMessage _result;

    protected override void ConfigureTestServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        base.ConfigureTestServices(services);
        // replace here the service you use to read settings with mocks
        // e.g: services.Replace(typeof(IConfiguration),...)
    }

    protected override async Task Given()
    {
        _url = "api/clients?name=foo";
    }

    protected override async Task When()
    {
        _result = await HttpClient.GetAsync(_url);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Then_It_Should_Return_200_Ok()
    {
        _result.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

IMPORTANT: The above configuration allows overriding registered services, appsettings files, etc. It's also possible to overwrite a specific setting value by playing with environment variables.

Simply set any environment variable like `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("Whichever__Whatever", "strongerPreferredValue");` and the `Whichever:Whatever` setting in `appsettings.Test.json` or `appsettings.json` will be replaced.

**OPTION B** As it seems you may want to run those tests in a "real" environment, maybe you don't use the TestServer. I would advice against that though.

If it's a smoke or prod test, you want the real thing, nothing fake. Otherwise it's not a true smoke test because it does not guarantee that it functions well for end users.

If it's some kind of integration tests under a controlled environment, but running as a process as any production app would normally do, I would consider having a separate environment for those kind of things, where you don't have to dynamically change anything and where you just configure the settings for THAT environment.

If, still, you consider it's best to run an app and dynamically modify settings, the best you can do is abstract away the functionality that reads settings and make sure everything within your application uses this new abstraction to retrieve settings.

For example, you could create a wrapper for `IConfiguration`

```
public interface IMySettings
{
    object GetSettings(string name);
}
```

and the implementation can be

```
public class MySettings : IMySettings
{
   private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
   
   public MySettings(IConfiguration configuration)
   {
      _configuration = configuration;
   }

   public object GetSettings(string name)
   {
      //Here your logic to return the real setting value as per environment, environment variable or appsettings. Or a custom one.
      // or delegate in the IConfiguration as normal
      return _configuration.GetValue<object>("Whichever:Whatever");
   }
}
```

Don't forget to register the `services.AddTransient<IMySettings, MySettings>();` and inject the `IMySettings` in whichever controller or service where you need access to settings.

PS: For the test approach in OptionA, I have a video (in Spanish, sorry) that goes through that approach. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dyVEayGwU3I
Also a code example is at https://gitlab.com/diegosasw/arquitectura-software/-/tree/master/src/testing